# I want to load a page content in a variable with .load and then alert it

Tags: jquery

but below code doesnt work. submit.php: echo "Hi";

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    var input;
    input.load("submit.php");       
    alert(input);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think an empty var ('input') has a load() method ?

Answer (score 3):

Please check jquery $.post [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Also check jquery api docs [here](http://jqapi.com) for further reference

Typically ajax request looks like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'sample.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(response){ alert(response); },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

`sample.php`

```
<?
    echo "hai";
?>
```

Demo for $.load **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/ntfGk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .load() like this

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Does not return anything to a var.
Make use of the [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand that jQuery is a framework that extends javascript functionalities. To use it you have to have jquery object. You have declared javascript variable and you are trying to call jquery function on it.

If you want a variable with result you can do this:

```
jQuery.get("submit.php", function(response) {
   //here you have response that contains submit.php response
   alert(response);
});
```

sorry I just noticed @Dhiraj answer. This method does the same thing only using get witch can be done with his answer just by switching "POST" to "GET".